# What is the format to add java Localdate parameters when creating objects in BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej, localdate

I'm using BlueJ to do a Java Project. 
In my Java code, I have created a LocalDate variable in one training classes. But when I tried to create an object I cannot enter the local date. 
It seems like the format that I'm entering is incorrect. 
I tried with several different formats.

[image]

Comment: @CaleBanfield Thanks, I remembered seeing this before.

Comment: Thank you!! Used the format "java.time.LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 30)". And it worked.